# Equivalent Syntax Anonymous Type from c# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, razor, typehead

I have a syntax problem in a conversion from c# code to vb.net code
In a Razor view I have this declaration

`new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }`

I'm not able to translate this in VB.net

In my HtmlHelper when I receive the object "additionalViewData" (that is the object declared above) i obtain only

```
[class]= form-control
```

and I have no trace about the htmlAttributes

Thanks

Comment: With basic research many, many things become pretty simple. **[Anonymous Types (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/anonymous-types)**

Comment: downvoting 'cause of no effort

Comment: I read that article before posting my question. But I didn't find the solution. In a positive case I didn't ask into this forum

Comment: At least post a code snippet with valid syntax (no 2nd closing brace and no context).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
New With {Key .htmlAttributes = New With {Key .[class] = "form-control"}}
```